# EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to limit video recording duration by 5 seconds. I am using default camera and this code:

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 5);
```

Now it works fine on Samsung S6, it stops recording after 5 seconds but I just tested on HTC older version and it just keeps recording after 5s pass. Any suggestion of how to limit the recording time for all of the phones?

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestion of how to limit the recording time for all of the phones?

Record it yourself, using a camera API (e.g., `android.hardware.Camera`) and `MediaRecorder`, or a library that wraps around those.

`ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` invokes a third-party camera app, and there are *hundreds* of these. `EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT` is a request, and not all camera apps will honor it.

Comment: Tried many 3rd party apps and I gave up on them as I have to many problems with them, phone crashes with no reason at all or it just doesn't run. Tried mediaRecorder, worked fine, but had to implement camera into my app which didnt worked